# Storing FTP passwords for wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, passwords, storage

I am writing a wordpress plugin which will needs to connect to one or more FTP servers periodically to check for files. I would need to store the passwords to the FTP server in a database in a way that my plugin can read the passwords and use it to connect to the FTP server. Since I would need to retrieve the password from my program, I can't use bcrypt. One possibility is to use openssl_encrypt like so.

`$hash = openssl_encrypt($password, "AES-128-ECB", SECRETKEY);`

My question is, would storing the secret key in the wp-config file be an acceptable solution so far as security is concerned? What is the best practise in this regard?